# simple grade calculator using arrow functions Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple grade calculator that uses a function to determine a letter grade. I am using an arrow function to take a number and print out 'P' if its greater or equal to 70 and 'F' otherwise.

My script is not working properly. Anyone have good suggestions?

```
'use strict';

var grade = (a) => { if (a >= 70)
  return 'P';
  } else {
    return 'F';
  }
}

grade(80)
```

Comment: What isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: so basically my whole script is not working. I get a Syntax error when running the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are missing braces, check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/qmhwy5gu/ (see the result in console)

with this code it works

```
    var grade = (a) => { if (a >= 70){
    console.log('P');
    }else{
    console.log('F');
    }
}

grade(80)
```

Comment: it works now but why does undefined print when using this function?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a curly brace after your if statement

```
if(a >= 70)
```

should be

```
if(a >= 70) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you say "if it is greater or equal to 70" but your condition means "lower than or equal to 70".

And you have a syntax error, missing a `{` after the condition.

Finally, a shorter way of writing that arrow function would be:

```
var grade = a => (a >= 70) ? 'P' : 'F'
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that but I don't think that the only problem though.